# How to natively enable JSONP for existing WCF service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, json, jsonp

I have a an existing service like the below method:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class SomeService : ISomething
{
    public SomeListResults SomeList(SomeParams someParams)
    {
          ....
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to allow JSONP calls and also JSON at the same time (detect it). Is this native?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update your config to look like:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetframework="4.0">
    <authentication mode="None">
  </authentication></compilation></system.web>
  <system.webserver>
    <modules runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests="true">
  </modules></system.webserver>
  <system.servicemodel>
    <servicehostingenvironment **aspnetcompatibilityenabled**="true">
    <standardendpoints>
      <webscriptendpoint>
        <standardendpoint **crossdomainscriptaccessenabled**="true" name="">
      </standardendpoint></webscriptendpoint>
    </standardendpoints>
  </servicehostingenvironment></system.servicemodel>
</configuration>
```

[See here for a blog post](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/06/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html) providing a walkthrough of creating a wcf service that's accessible cross-domain.

This will enable your service to accept requests from cross-domain sources.

In terms of determining whether to pad your response (the p in jsonp),

Thanks to @carlosfigueira for this:

> If using .Net 4 JSONP is supported natively. As long as the request has a query string parameter called "callback" (this name can be configured), the response will be padded with the function name
>   .

Otherwise, you'll need to write a custom message inspector that pads the response appropriately.

Comment: You don't need to write a custom inspector - in .NET 4.0 JSONP is supported natively. As long as the request has a query string parameter called "callback" (this name can be configured), the response will be padded with the function name (given that crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled is set to true, as you mentioned)

Comment: @carlosfigueira Many thanks for this nugget of information, my last forays into the world of jsonp and WCF were in .Net 3.5. Answer now updated. Great blog by the way!

Answer (score 2):

The new JSONP feature is exposed via the WebHttpBinding. The configuration for the CustomersService would looks like this:

```
 <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="ServiceSite.CustomersService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="ServiceSite.CustomersService"
                behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
    </service>
  </services>
```

Consuming JSONP with jQuery

```
 // Get the JsonP data
 $.getJSON('http://localhost:65025/CustomersService.svc/GetCustomers?callback=?', null, function (customers) {
      alert('Received ' + customers.length + ' Customers');
 });
```