# Jquery Not Showing Json Data From WCF

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, cross-domain

I have Written A Simple WCF Method.It is returning Correct values But It is showing 200

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:60770/Service.svc/GetContacts?calback=?",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: "{}",
        crossDomain: true,
        processdata: true,
        success: function (response) {
        //    var data = response;
            alert("data.FirstName");
        },

        error: function (e) {
            alert('error ' + e.status + ' ' + e.responseText);

        }
    });
```

It is going to error and when i am checking the response using FireBug. it is showing Json there.

Please Help!!

Comment: what does the returned data look like?

Comment: And what's the error status/text?

Comment: for jsonp requests dataType should be `jsonp`, type -> `get`

Comment: {"d":"hello"}, responseText is undefined and status is 200

Comment: Full error function signature is :Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ), so change it and read errorThrown

Comment: I tried JsonP as well same issue

Comment: When i added a Full error function,it still returns undefined

Comment: And testStatus param - "parsingError"?

Comment: Error: jQuery17108239092557672146_1362848154261 was not called

Comment: any guess? waiting for reply..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing JSON and JSONP here.

You have `crossDomain:true`, absolute URL, but pointing to local host. Then you have typo in example `?calback=?` (missing "l" and 2nd "?").

In JSONP your:

```
/GetContacts?calback=myFunction
```

you expect result like: `myFunction({"d":"Hello"})`

`myFunction` will be called automatically. In your case "?" is name of the function. And WCF, .NET 4 it supports JSONP, but you have to enable it:
[How to natively enable JSONP for existing WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219579/how-to-natively-enable-jsonp-for-existing-wcf-service)

So I would switch-off `crossDomain:true` and provide relative url without `callback` parameter, or read a bit on JSONP:
[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: Thanks for responding..i have Cross domain to use for example : www.example.com/Services.svc but things are not working so i created a service on my local.please guide me how to make it work with cross domain.

Comment: You have enough clues now to fix it. Just read read those 2 short articles yourself. ;)