# Displaying jsonp data on web page

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I'm trying to display data using jsonp but for some reason it doesn't wanna display on the web page.

```
function test() 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "http://localhost/api/company",  //web api is hosted on iss 8
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) 
        {
            $("#test").append(data[5].Company);
        }
    });
}
```

Please note the data return from the server is just fine. I tested this by executing the test function via google chrome and checking the response in network tab.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: Do you mean the response?

Comment: Yes. What is its structure? Do you definitely have at least 6 elements in your array? Also, does your code hit the `append` line?

Comment: Hi lee, the response is XML and yes it does have 6 elements.

Comment: XML? It's not in JSON format? Please show a sample.

Comment: Hi lee sorry it is Json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you read a good explanation between JSON and JSON with Padding (JSONP) here in order to have a good understanding of what is going on:
[Can anyone explain what JSONP is, in layman terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms)

First off the URL your calling needs to support JSONP. Not all webservices, rest interfaces, etc support it *even if they produce JSON*.

Secondly, you need to include a **?callback=?** in your URL, in order to use JSONP from jquery.

You add ?callback=? to your URL, for example:

```
var url = 'URL?callback=?';
  $.getJSON(url, function(jsonp){
    $("#jsonp-response").html(JSON.stringify(jsonp, null, 2));
  });
```

You also need to test if the actual service supports JSONP, and you can do that opening in your browser your webservice with ?callback=something added

```
http://localhost/api/company?callback=callbackID
```

If the API supports jsonp you should see in your browser an output like:

```
callbackID({
    JSON DOCUMENT HERE
});
```

In the next section I'm including links to show what a standard JSON only response is, and what a JSONP response is.

**Live Example Using Twitter API**

When you use getJson to send the request and have ?callback=? jquery automatically adds a callback id.

The webserver gets a request such as and wraps the data up wth the callback name (this case "a"):

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?since_id=91770779645124609&q=test&callback=a
```

If you try the same request without the callback you see only JSON which cannot be consumed cross-site:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?since_id=91770779645124609&q=test
```

Comment: Hi Meewok thanks for the replay. Do you know how can i include the callback?

Comment: I believe the web service is configured to accept JSONP request as it is returning data(response can be seen in network tab).

Comment: I've updated the response to answer your questions. If the webservice supports JSONP the output should change when your access via the browser with ?callback= added to the URL. If you want you can provide also the webservice URL and I can have a look.

Comment: Now the web api is being called like this http://localhost/api/company/jsonp?callback=jQuery19105627042897976935_1365926219165&_=1365926219166 and it returns a bad 400 Bad Request. Does this mean the web api is not configured to accept Jsonp?

Comment: You'll actually just see the JSON as output, without the callback.

Comment: 400 means the web api is expecting different syntax for your request.

Comment: @Raju 400 means the web api is expecting different syntax for your request.

Comment: @Michael Mior Thanks, I added a live example with twitter that shows how the server responds with the callback.

Comment: Thanks for your help Meewok. The web api is not currently supported to handle jsonp responses as the response returned from it is json. Will need to read some tutorials in order to support jsonp

Comment: YW, if you saw a difference between http://localhost/api/company?callback=callbackID and http://localhost/api/company there's a chance it is supported. Otherwise no :(

Comment: Nope no difference they are identical. Does WCF support JSONP?

Comment: I think maybe these could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219579/how-to-natively-enable-jsonp-for-existing-wcf-service  http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery/