# consume web service through url in other domain in json

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have created a wcf service in our server and it is hosted in IIS when i consume this web method in my html page which is in same solution or different solution in same server (ex: service url://www.xyz.com/projectname/service.svc/methodname
and domain url://www.xyz.com/projectname) 
when i call this url in ajax jquery with type='post' and datatype="J son" i am successfully getting response from my web method.but issue is when i create a sample html page in different server with different domain name (domain url: //www.abc.com/projectname and service 
url //www.xyz.com/projectname/service.svc/methodname )
i am unable to invoke the web service or i don't know exactly is it invoking the web method and it is displaying error message ,can any one please help me how to over come with any issue

Comment: Browsers enforce what is known as the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) which prevents you from making cross domain AJAX calls.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities for making cross domain AJAX calls:

- [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (works only with GET requests if you use jquery and only with JSON response payloads) - your service should support JSONP response instead of simple JSON. Basically this means that it should wrap the standard JSON in a callback function that should be passed as parameter. You may take a look here for how to natively enable JSONP support in a WCF service here: [How to natively enable JSONP for existing WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219579/how-to-natively-enable-jsonp-for-existing-wcf-service)
- [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (works with all HTTP verbs) - your web service must return the proper `Access-Control-Allow-*` response headers. And here's an example of how you could create a custom message inspector in WCF that would append those headers: http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html