# how to resolve jquery "parser error"

Tags: ajax, wcf, jquery, wcf-rest

i am trying to make a **ajax** call with dataType JSONP from my client side script, the service uri belongs to a restful wcf service which hosted locally.

Below is my client side script:

```
function callback() {
     alert("callback");
 }
 

     $.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost:999/Service1.svc/Get/rajesh",

         // the name of the callback parameter
         jsonp: "callback",

         // tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
         dataType: "jsonp",

         // work with the response
         success: function (response) {
             console.log(response); // server response
         },
         error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("errorThrown: " + errorThrown + " textStatus:" + textStatus);
        }
     });
```

i am get below Errors:

**1) Error Alert message**
[image]

```
errorThrown: Error: jQuery1910367527295252279_1387528759305 was not called textStatus:parsererror
```

**2)Error at console**

[image]

console error json object is incorrect but i think it is current.
any help is appreciated

Comment: Try putting it inside `$(function() {})` and check if that makes any difference

Comment: @RononDex: It has nothing to do with DOM ready.

Comment: well, that jquery[number] you got there is common for jquery. It adds those id's on html elements that it uses in the dom. That's why I thought it might make a different

Answer (score 3):

From the error, it looks like your server is responding with [JSON](http://json.org), not [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), as the error is quoting:

```
{"GetEmployeeResult":"success"}
```

...which is JSON, but a JSONP response would look like:

```
jQuery34978249823_23049820394({"GetEmployeeResult":"success"})
```

...where the function name `jQuery34978249823_23049820394` comes from the callback parameter in the request (and will vary every time).

To correct it, have the server return JSONP, or change your `$.ajax` call to use JSON (assuming the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) isn't an issue).

Comment: I tried by replacing jsonp with Json, still it is going to error function display jqXHR.status as 0 and textStatus as error

Comment: @VivekP: That would suggest you're trying to do something cross-origin and JSONP is the better option.

Comment: @Crowder Yes, to achieve cross-origin i used jsonp.

Comment: @VivekP: Right. So the **server** has to respect its side of that contract, and return JSONP, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

See answer available Here:

[How to natively enable JSONP for existing WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219579/how-to-natively-enable-jsonp-for-existing-wcf-service)

For a possible solution. It sounds like you need to re-configure your wcf to return JSONP and not JSON.