# getjson - not returning object to console

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to retrieve a json feed every 1 second. The URL that I am trying to retrieve displays JSON in the browser but will not be retrieved via a jquery getJSON

http://www.ridestreamline.com/Services/JSONPRelay.svc/GetMapVehiclePoints

```
function getBusLoc() {
$.getJSON('http://www.ridestreamline.com/Services/JSONPRelay.svc/GetMapVehiclePoints?callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    setTimeout(getBusLoc, 1000);
})
}
getBusLoc()
```

It has something to do with the above link. What am I missing? [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/C99g6/2/)

Comment: [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: shoudnt adding the ?callback=? fix that? fiddle and above updated

Comment: The server should serve JSONP, not just JSON. Tell whoever owns that service to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8219579/447356) and follow what its answer says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of same origin policy, you can't sent ajax request from host A to host B, you can use jsonp instead (if your service supports this) , or if you has control to server side and you don't mind to old browsers you can use x-access-control-allow-origin http header in response to OPTIONS request (more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)