# WCF returning a JSONP or custom result format

Tags: c#, ajax, json, wcf, jsonp

Well, I have a WCF service that returns a custom object with some properties I need to use.

```
[DataContract]
public class CommonJsonResponse {

    [DataMember]
    public object Data { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    private string errorMessage;
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage {
        get {
            return errorMessage;
        }
        set {
            errorMessage = value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
                Success = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public CommonJsonResponse() {
        Success = true;
    }
}
```

All my service methods will return this object with the other needed data inside the `Data` property. I have a method like this:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public CommonJsonResponse DoSomething(int value, string callback) {

    var response = new CommonJsonResponse();        
    response.Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        GetItemIntoDatabaseByGivenValue(value));

    return response;
}


$.ajax({
    url: serviceUrl + '/DoSomething',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { value: 1 },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, response, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        if (xhr.responseText) {
            var err = xhr.responseText;
            if (err) {
                error(err);
            } else {
                error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
            }
        }
    });
```

Ok, once I want to work with cross-domains, the idea is return a `JSONP` object. I know AJAX add some parameters - like the `callback` parameter above - into the request string. I know as well that, in order to return a properly `JSONP` object, I need to do something like that below:

```
var properlyResult = callback + "(" + response + ");";
```

Ok, since my method is returning a `CommonJsonResponse`, is there a way to override the response will be added to the `HttpContext`? I mean, the idea is get the `CommonJsonResponse` object will be sent and wrap it into the string above in order to generate a properly result and then put this properly result into the `HttpContext` will be sent back to the browser.

Thanks for you help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.

I've used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219579/how-to-natively-enable-jsonp-for-existing-wcf-service):

Thanks to [rich.okelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930847/rich-okelly) (first answer) for the tip that .NET framework 4.0+ does the `JSONP` parse nativetely.

Thanks also to [Rachit Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3572582/rachit-patel) (second answer) for the `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled` attribute tip on the `webHttpBinding`.