# error calling WCF service from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, ajax, wcf

I am new to angularjs. While learning I have created a test applicaton in which I created a ajax enabled WCF service and a test page with angularjs code.
When using $http.get() the control does not reach the service method and error is displayed.

My angularjs test page is as below

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
        <div ng-app="myAngularJs" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

It does not do anything just trying to reach the service.
the controller is in js file as below

```
angular.module("myAngularJs", []).controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        url: "http://localhost:17040/Service1.svc/getData",
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function (data) {
        debugger;
        console.log(data);
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data.data.d);
    });
});
```

I have created WCF service in same project by adding a new ajax enabled WCF service. Its code is as below

```
[OperationContract]        
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/getData/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string getData()
    {
        ServiceReference.WcfServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference.WcfServiceClient();
        string data = obj.getTestAjaxget();
        return data;
    }
```

My issue is the control never reaches the service but error is displayed in browser console as below
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

My web.config is as below

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" name=""></binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="ServiceAPI.WcfServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
            <enableWebScript />
          </behavior>
            <behavior name="testApplication.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>              
        </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="testApplication.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="testApplication.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding" contract="testApplication.Service1" />
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:6168/WcfService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAPI.WcfServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
     binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference.WcfService" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: first hit this in browser and check if your project is working 
 http://localhost:17040/Service1.svc/getData

Comment: No It displays error : Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services. I removed crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" from web.config. but still the control does not reach the service

Comment: @GhulamMohayudin After removing crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled='true' from web.config now the service gets called from my application. But I am not able to reach the other WCF service by calling its method from this WCF service. Error is "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.".

Comment: from browser you can only hit services which allow only GET method, is your WCF project and Project where you are calling the service is in the same domain?

Comment: My current WCF that is reached (say WCF serviceA) is in same solution. But the Wcf serviceReference object I am creating in getData() is for the Wcf Service which is in another domain.

Comment: if you are making cross domain request, you need to allow it using this configuration 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219579/how-to-natively-enable-jsonp-for-existing-wcf-service

Comment: @GhulamMohayudin I tried adding the suggested configuration options in web.config of service application but still the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150685/discussion-between-ghulam-mohayudin-and-sam).